# TabBarImage is not resized properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbaritem

I am trying to assign a 60x60 px image to the `tabBarItem.image`:

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_settings@2x.png"];
```

I have read in HIG, that I should put 60x60 px image for the Retina display. But what I get is an incorrectly sized image:

[image]

If I make it 30x30px ,it looks bad too (not like for Retina).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to specify that the `@2x.png` image is used.  For your project, just add these two images in Xcode:

> tab_settings@2x.png  (60x60 pixels)
>
> tab_settings.png     (30x30 pixels)

And then in your code use this:

```objc
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_settings"];
```

iOS will determine whether to use the 30x30, or 60x60 image for you.  It's a really nice design by Apple.

Comment: I know it, it doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: @wzbozon, that's the way to provide tab bar icons.  Please double-check the sizes on both versions of your image.  And don't use the string `"tab_settings@2x.png"` in your code.  You should never, ever specify an image name with `"@2x"` in it, *in the code*.

Comment: yes, I checked and it started to work. Looks like there should be both images for Retina and not Retina. I was putting only for Retina.